# SUM() Query returning 0 for every entry

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

So this is an example of the query I'm trying to run:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
conn = sqlite3.connect('nfl_data.db')
c = conn.cursor()
newdf = c.execute("""SELECT name, SUM('Rush Yards')
                  FROM collegernr WHERE name ='Doug Martin'
                  GROUP BY name""")
df = pd.DataFrame(newdf.fetchall())
print(df)
```

I have players with several years of college statistics and I want to sum these values so that each player's name only appears once and the values for each column are their college totals.

Running this query returns 0 for every row and column (if i include more variables and remove WHERE name='Doug Martin') for this version it returns:

```
             0    1
0  Doug Martin  0.0
```

All the columns of interest are classified as REAL or INTEGER and there are no NULL values, only 0s, and in the case of Doug Martin, there aren't even any 0s, all strictly positive values.

I thought at first maybe the year column was creating an issue but deleting it didn't fix anything.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious after looking at this for so long. I apologize if I've created a duplicate question I couldn't find anything with a quick google or search in the search bar

Comment: Forget about the non-MySQL stuff and see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query.

Comment: Send the `describe <TABLE_NAME>` of your table to be able to help...

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to using SQL so I wasn't sure what to include with my question. I cant quite figure out how to get something akin to describe <TABLE_NAME> to work within python. Can you let me know what info you need? Columns are: index INTEGER, name TEXT, RnR_Plays INTEGER, Rec_TD INTEGER, Rec_Yards REAL, Receptions REAL, Rush_Att REAL, Rush_TD INTEGER, RnR_Yards INTEGER, RnR_TD INTEGER, yr INTEGER, college TEXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is parsing `'Rush Yards'` as a *string literal*.

Interpreted in a numeric context, that evaluates to 0. As a demonstration:

```
SELECT 'Rush Yards', 'Rush Yards' + 0
```

If the intent is to reference a column name, the identifier can be enclosed in **backticks**:

```
SELECT `Rush Yards`, 'Rush Yards' FROM collegernr
       ^          ^
```

---

```
              SELECT `name`
                   , SUM(`Rush Yards`)
                FROM `collegernr`
               WHERE `name` = 'Doug Martin'
               GROUP BY `name`
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's fixed it for me. I wasn't sure how to reference column names with spaces and so I enclosed in quotes and since it worked I never thought about it.

Comment: Double quotes for the identifiers would be a better choice than backticks. Standard SQL uses double quotes, SQLite supports backticks for compatibility with MySQL's non-standard behavior.

Comment: I should have more carefully qualified my answer as addressing MySQL [ [tag:mysql] ] and MariaDB [ [tag:mariadb] ], which use bacticks to escape identifiers. If `sql_mode` includes `ANSI_QUOTES`, then yes, identifiers can be escaped by enclosing them in double quotes. Without that setting, tokens enclosed in double quotes are interpreted as string literals. In SQL Server [ [tag:sql-server] ] identifiers are escaped using square brackets. Oracle [ [tag:oracle] ] more closely conforms to the ANSI SQL standard by always and only using double quotes to escape identifiers.